# vue-router — remember entry URL and redirect after login (beforeEach)

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am scratching my head trying to figure out the logic in my vue router so so Vue will remember an entry URL, redirect to "/Login" if not authenticated, then redirect to the entry URL after login.

I think I've just been staring at this too long and could use some fresh eyes. Thoughts on where I've gone astray here?

```
...

let entryUrl = null;
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  let locStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData"));
  let stateStore = state.getters.getUserData;
  let userData = locStorage || stateStore;
  let isAuthenticated = userData.token !== "" && userData.token !== undefined;
  let url;
  if (to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (!isAuthenticated) {
      if (to.fullPath !== "/login" && to.fullPath !== "/") {
        entryUrl = to.fullPath;
        console.log("setting", entryUrl);
      }
      next({ name: "Login" });
    } else {
      console.log("entry", entryUrl);
      url = entryUrl || "/";
      entryUrl = null;
      console.log("url", url);
      next();
    }
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) store for that. In the store you could save the url before the redirect to the `/login` and after the login you could check if there is an url saved and redirect to that.

You only have to make sure that you pass in the store instance into your logic which creates the router-handler.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a shot in the morning. Brain melt. I thought about that, or localStorage, but it seems like both are not necessary if I could get all my nested if/thens sorted out.

Comment: Vuex store has the advantage that its state and getters are reactive. For me it is easier to use it inside your app.